# How to do firebase multipath push?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen multipath update example. But before updating any data i have to push it at first place for which i was wondering if there is something called as multipath push?

I want to simultaneously push data under different set of nodes.
eg: Firebase scheme

```
-Examinations
  - pushIdLk12203425
  - pushIdML0124245
-RightChoices
  - pushIdLk12203425
  - pushIdML0124245
-Questions
  - pushIdLk12203425
  - pushIdML0124245
```

When i push value under examination node, same values or different values as per my backend architecture have to be pushed under RightChoices and Questions Node. Right now i am doing this using .then callback approach.

I push data under Examinations and then in its .then callback i push in RightChoice and Questions node.

But my concern is what if user closes the app and data just reaches Examinations node and never reaches RightChoices and Questions Node.

I am trying to figure out a better way of having data consistency.

Thanks.

Note: RightChoices and Questions are kept under different nodes for having a better security architecture and i cannot change the schema.
Would be grateful if somebody can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is a _"multipath push"_?

Comment: please see the updated question @AndréKool

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to create a push ID and use that ID in several locations?

Comment: Yes. It will help me to use it as a foreign key for other nodes. So I want to make sure data gets updated consistently else Derz a chance the backend architecture may break due to connectivity issues, etc. So I want it to be either all or non like firebase multipath updates.

Comment: In that case I really think an answer has already been given below. (It's currently for android but simular to how it works for the web version) I will edit a little bit of code comments in that answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `.update()`

Have a look here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields:

```
function writeMultipath(pushID1, pushID2) {

  var data = {
    id1: pushID1,
    id2: pushID2
  }; 

  // Write the new data simultaneously to your DB-locations
  var updates = {};
  updates['/Examinations/'] = data;
  updates['/RightChoices/'] = data;
  updates['/Questions/'] = data;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry. Please see the updated question. Would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: yes. I am looking for javascript solution. Would be grateful if answer can be updated.

Comment: @AndréKool can you help me out on this?